# identity id column in sql table doesn't start at 1

Tags: sql

I ran a delete script to delete all rows that had an id greater than 0 to clear the table and now when I try to add rows to the table, the id starts off where it left off from before. How can I delete the info in the table so the id starts off at 1 again?

Comment: Does it really matter?  usually when I hear questions like this, it's because the developer is attempting to assign meaning to an identity value, which is almost never a good design.

Comment: Why do you care?  The only purpose for an auto-increment id (MySQL) or Sequence (Oracle) is to provide a unique identifier -- its value should be immaterial.  If you do attempt to reset it then anything that uses the original as a foreign key will now break.

Comment: Perhaps he's testing an import routine and likes to start from 1 each time, because he's familiar with the data that way.

Answer (score 5):

Delete statement doesnt reset the identity value. Use Truncate table command if you want identity value to be reset. something like this..

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Table_Name
```

This will empty the table and reset the identity value.

Only use TRUNCATE when you want all the rows to be deleted. As it does not allow you to use WHERE clause.

Comment: The disclaimer was so much important!! :-P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible in the same table. Which database are you using? In previous versions of MS Access compacting the database used to work but not any more. I don't think SQL Server allows that either. The only way is to copy the records from this table to a new table, delete the old table and rename the new table to the old table name.

Answer (score 0):

In MS-SQL you can have a play with `DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 0)`